# AlarmManager only firing when device is restarted

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an app that sends a weekly notification.  It's supposed to fire at 8:15 Thursday morning; however, I only received an update this week after restarting my phone (after 8:15 AM yesterday).  The alarm is set in MainActivity on the first run, and I implemented BootReceiver so that the alarm is reset if the user shuts their phone off.  Does anyone know if I've got a logical error somewhere that I've missed?

Edit: So it's firing with each restart now. How do I go about fixing this? The way the notification functions makes it a big issue to be sending notifications with each restart (it increments a point value used to redeem rewards).

Here's the section of code from MainActivity:

```
public void manageNotifications() {
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, java.util.Calendar.THURSDAY);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    /*
    sets alarm manager to go off at 8:15 in the morning every 7 days on Thursday
     */
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
}//end manageNotifications
```

Here's my BootReceiver class:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, java.util.Calendar.THURSDAY);
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    /*
    sets alarm manager to go off at 8:15 in the morning every 7 days on Thursday
     */
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

}

And here's the AlarmReceiver code that gets called from both BootReceiver and MainActivity on the first run:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
Intent notificationResultIntent;
ArrayList<Show> shows;
SharedPreferences spSpreadsheets, spNotifications;
final String showSpreadsheetURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ax2-gUY33i_pRHZIwR8AULy6-nbnAbM8Qm5-CGISevc/gviz/tq";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("AlarmReceiver created");
    spNotifications = context.getSharedPreferences("notificationToggle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    spSpreadsheets = context.getSharedPreferences("spreadsheets", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (spNotifications.getBoolean("notifications", false)) {
        int nextRegularShowIndex = 0, i = 0;

        shows = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            if (spSpreadsheets.getString("showsSpreadsheet", "").equals(""))
                getShows(context);
            shows = processShowsJson(new JSONObject(spSpreadsheets.getString("showsSpreadsheet", "")));

            while (shows.get(i).getShowTime() != 0) {
            /*
            checks for first instance of a regular showtime
             */
                i++;
                nextRegularShowIndex = i;
            }
            checkForPastShows();
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                    .setContentTitle("Comedy Club of Jacksonville")
                    .setContentText(shows.get(nextRegularShowIndex).getComedian() + " headlines this weekend at the Comedy " +
                            "Club of Jacksonville.  Click to read more.")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            notificationResultIntent = new Intent(context, ThisWeekendFromNotification.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(ThisWeekend.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationResultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
            System.out.println("Notification built");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end onReceive
    }
}
```

Comment: Use **`adb shell dumpsys alarm`** to confirm that your alarm is being set as expected. Use `Log` calls or debugger breakpoints to determine what of your code is being run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from my reddit comment: It definitely looks like you're setting the alarm to go off in the past. The `Calendar`apis are a bit weird.

```
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, java.util.Calendar.THURSDAY);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
```

This code will set the Calendar to be Thursday at 8:15 am *of the current week*. So if the user restarts their phone on Friday morning, this time would be pointing to the *previous* Thursday morning. This will cause `AlarmManager` to trigger your alarm immediately per the docs for `setRepeating()` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

> If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately, with an alarm count depending on how far in the past the trigger time is relative to the repeat interval.

EDIT -- following up on your comment on how to fix:

The quick and dirty way would be something like this

```
long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
if (alarmTime < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    alarmTime += DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS;
}

alarmManager.set( ... alarmTime ... );
```

I used to hate hearing this when asking questions about the Java Calendar api as well, but using the Joda-Time library (or in your case [Joda-Time Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android)) will save you a lot of pain in the long run. The apis are much clearer and easier to work with.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you for the followup.  So then to fix it, I need to schedule the alarm for the next Thursday in BootReceiver?  As in setTimeInMillis (System.currentTimeInMillis() + 1000*60*60*24*7); ?